# Class hestabit\craftajaxinate\assetbundles\CraftAjaxinate\CraftAjaxinateAsset does not exist

Tags: plugins

Maybe someone can assist me with this error? I cannot find the fix for this:

```
ReflectionException: Class hestabit\craftajaxinate\assetbundles\CraftAjaxinate\CraftAjaxinateAsset does not exist in /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:508
Stack trace:
#0 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(508): ReflectionClass->__construct('hestabit\\crafta...')
#1 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(386): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('hestabit\\crafta...')
#2 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\di\Container->build('hestabit\\crafta...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('hestabit\\crafta...', Array, Array)
#4 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(286): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#5 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(259): yii\web\AssetManager->loadBundle('hestabit\\crafta...', Array, true)
#6 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(287): yii\web\AssetManager->getBundle('hestabit\\crafta...')
#7 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/hestabit/craft-ajaxinate/src/variables/CraftAjaxinateVariable.php(43): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('hestabit\\crafta...')
#8 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php(1507): hestabit\craftajaxinate\variables\CraftAjaxinateVariable->loadMoreVariable(Array)
#9 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Template.php(106): twig_get_attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig\Source), Object(hestabit\craftajaxinate\variables\CraftAjaxinateVariable), 'loadMoreVariabl...', Array, 'method', false, false)
#10 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/11/1117038cbf0f703a8f8cb0df612f700956c8ad40a1ddacec50cc0ca4500c12cd.php(79): craft\helpers\Template::attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig\Source), Object(hestabit\craftajaxinate\variables\CraftAjaxinateVariable), 'loadMoreVariabl...', Array, 'method')
#11 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_2ad062c5ed74974e218ed2dc089bb6fc41752aefb27696ab5d4c5e5c72beac07->block_body(Array, Array)
#12 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/18/18bfc4f9d8192de40c7e427e6814cf79739256bc53e1b5a977be43d0c4fdcbf3.php(352): Twig\Template->displayBlock('body', Array, Array)
#13 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_18da55aebf6245a31f6b7c3d737e30029a220be45c7544039f508f35067ba057->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#14 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#15 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/11/1117038cbf0f703a8f8cb0df612f700956c8ad40a1ddacec50cc0ca4500c12cd.php(46): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#16 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_2ad062c5ed74974e218ed2dc089bb6fc41752aefb27696ab5d4c5e5c72beac07->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#17 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#18 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#19 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
#20 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(318): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
#21 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(390): Twig\Environment->render('naujienos', Array)
#22 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(451): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('naujienos', Array)
#23 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(257): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('naujienos', Array, 'site')
#24 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php(100): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('naujienos', Array)
#25 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('naujienos', Array)
#26 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#28 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(190): yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#29 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#30 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(274): yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#31 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104): craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#32 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(259): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#33 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#34 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/web/index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#35 {main}

Next yii\di\NotInstantiableException: Failed to instantiate component or class "hestabit\craftajaxinate\assetbundles\CraftAjaxinate\CraftAjaxinateAsset". in /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:510
Stack trace:
#0 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(386): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('hestabit\\crafta...')
#1 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(171): yii\di\Container->build('hestabit\\crafta...', Array, Array)
#2 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('hestabit\\crafta...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(286): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#4 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(259): yii\web\AssetManager->loadBundle('hestabit\\crafta...', Array, true)
#5 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(287): yii\web\AssetManager->getBundle('hestabit\\crafta...')
#6 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/hestabit/craft-ajaxinate/src/variables/CraftAjaxinateVariable.php(43): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('hestabit\\crafta...')
#7 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php(1507): hestabit\craftajaxinate\variables\CraftAjaxinateVariable->loadMoreVariable(Array)
#8 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Template.php(106): twig_get_attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig\Source), Object(hestabit\craftajaxinate\variables\CraftAjaxinateVariable), 'loadMoreVariabl...', Array, 'method', false, false)
#9 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/11/1117038cbf0f703a8f8cb0df612f700956c8ad40a1ddacec50cc0ca4500c12cd.php(79): craft\helpers\Template::attribute(Object(craft\web\twig\Environment), Object(Twig\Source), Object(hestabit\craftajaxinate\variables\CraftAjaxinateVariable), 'loadMoreVariabl...', Array, 'method')
#10 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_2ad062c5ed74974e218ed2dc089bb6fc41752aefb27696ab5d4c5e5c72beac07->block_body(Array, Array)
#11 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/18/18bfc4f9d8192de40c7e427e6814cf79739256bc53e1b5a977be43d0c4fdcbf3.php(352): Twig\Template->displayBlock('body', Array, Array)
#12 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_18da55aebf6245a31f6b7c3d737e30029a220be45c7544039f508f35067ba057->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#13 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#14 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/11/1117038cbf0f703a8f8cb0df612f700956c8ad40a1ddacec50cc0ca4500c12cd.php(46): Twig\Template->display(Array, Array)
#15 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_2ad062c5ed74974e218ed2dc089bb6fc41752aefb27696ab5d4c5e5c72beac07->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#16 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#17 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Twig\Template->display(Array)
#18 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render(Array, Array)
#19 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(318): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(Array)
#20 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(390): Twig\Environment->render('naujienos', Array)
#21 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(451): craft\web\View->renderTemplate('naujienos', Array)
#22 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(257): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate('naujienos', Array, 'site')
#23 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php(100): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate('naujienos', Array)
#24 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('naujienos', Array)
#25 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#27 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(190): yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#28 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#29 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(274): yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#30 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104): craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#31 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(259): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#32 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#33 /home/telefonai/testing.telefonai.eu/web/index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#34 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this plugin isn't PSR-4 compliant and I'm guessing you're using Composer 2. The author of hestabit/craftajaxinate needs to correct the file naming.

Workarounds (dirty):

a) You could try using Composer 1

b) rename  *craftajaxinate* in vendor/hestabit/craftajaxinate/src/assetbundles/ to **C**raft**A**jaxinate